# Any good way to recycle filament?

Tags: pla, filament, recycling

With a good amount of failed prints, I now have a bunch of filament that is... trash.

Is there a good way to recycle it, or any services that you send them your lost filament to then melt it back into a new filament?

I kinda hate the amount of trash im producing with 3d printing.

Comment: You mean just failed prints that are in printed shape or rests of filament spools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recycle filament material from printed parts?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/59/how-to-recycle-filament-material-from-printed-parts) & [Uses for PLA scraps?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/uses-for-pla-scraps)

Comment: I throw fails in the hidden corner of my backyard. They are gone in a year.

Answer (score 0):

Many makers will reuse the filament from spaghetti prints as filler material when joining print sections together. Usually by heating it along the seams.